# kivy: pulsar un botón para cargar texto

Tags: python, programación-móvil, kivy

Quiero hacer un programa sencillo en kivy que me cargue un texto de un fichero al pulsar un botón.

Aquí está mi código en python:

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        def showtext():
            f = open("Prueba.txt","r")
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['textInp2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```

Y aquí mi archivo design.kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textInp2
            multiline: True
            readonly: True
            background_color: 0.92,0.89,0.75,1
            on_focus: self.focus = False 

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "cargar texto"
            on_release: root.showtext()
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa me da un error:

> *AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'showtext'*

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error y mostrar un texto guardado en un archivo al pulsar el botón?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showtest` a de ser un método de tu clase `MyWidget`. Lo estas definiendo dentro del constructor (`__init__`), debe estar fuera y debe tener como parámetro `self` ya que es un método de la clase.

Por otro lado debes cerrar el archivo después de leer de el mediante `f.close()` o puedes simplificarlo usando `with`:

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design2.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showtext(self):
        with open("Prueba.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['textInp2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```